# Vanilla plugin boilerplate and webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm using this
`https://github.com/janrembold/vanilla-plugin-boilerplate`
as starter to my plugin.
First thing first, my plugin is working fine, and now I want to add babel to the project, so I decided to joining a bandwagon, using **webpack** for the module bundler.
Here's the fiddle for working vanilla-plugin-boilerplate
https://jsfiddle.net/adhityoagam/1fk6p755/
and this is the webpack version of it, which has an error
https://jsfiddle.net/adhityoagam/1fk6p755/2/
The error says

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Boilerplate is not defined at window.onload ((index):233)

And here is my webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'mediamanager': './vendor.js',
  },
  output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
            fallback: 'style-loader',
            //resolve-url-loader may be chained before sass-loader if necessary
            use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']
          })
      },
      { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader" }
    ]
    },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin("[name].css"),
  ]
};
```

Please pinpoint my mistake and or why it doesn't work, thank you.

Comment: Contact the repository author and report an issue.

Comment: @zerkms oh, so, basically, there's nothing wrong with my setup? the vanilla plugin just dont suit with webpack?

Comment: "oh, so, basically, there's nothing wrong with my setup?" --- who knows... There is still a chance there are users of a tiny project that was abandoned almost 2 years here on SO, but I would not put a bet on it.

Answer (score 0):

this plugin boilerplate wasn't created with webpack in mind. And it is definitely not the best choice for a newly created webpack project.

Depending on the goal of your project you should search for a nice webpack kickstarter project that shows some nice webpack configuration and some script demos with ES6 or even better with TypeScript.

Best regards,
Jan